# Parse input file into environment variables

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that I want to read a settings files.  Each line of the settings file has a special meaning for the rest of the script (eg line1=source_directory line2=destination_directory)

Is there an easy way to parse the settings file into environment variables I can use in the rest of the script?

Edit:  I like the source idea but...  I was originally going have a file like this:

```
/my/source/dir
/my/dest/dir
```

not:

```
src_dir=/my/source/dir
dst_dir=/my/dest/dir
```

Can I somehow parse the first file?

Answer (score 1):

You can source it

```
. foo.sh
```

this will allow you to use all the variables defined in `foo.sh`.
You can also invoke using `source` keyword

```
source foo.sh
```

[More info](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

```
source: source filename [arguments]

    Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.
```

Answer (score 1):

A common trick is to source configuration files. On Red Hat systems, for instance, the system scripts in `/etc/rc.d` and `/etc/sysconfig` do this.

```
. /etc/prog.conf
```

This reads them as if they were scripts. This works great if the settings use `name=value` form and comments begin with `#`.

**Caution:** Make sure the configuration file is trusted since you're executing it like a script. It should be owned by the same user and group and have the same permissions as parent script.

Answer (score 0):

If your file just has values, you don't really "parse" it.

```
exec 3<config
read source <&3
read dest <&3
exec 3<-
```

You might want to add some flags to `read` if your values may contain whitespace, etc. I should perhaps change the answer to have `read -r` but I encourage you to [study the other available flags,](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html) too.